# Is it possible to make a 'broken' border with text for QLineEdit in PyQt/PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

Is it possible to style the input field in PyQt5/PySide2 to look like this:
[input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aas3R.png)

Official docs on styling QLineEdit (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlineedit) do not provide many examples.
So far I tried messing with border properties but I cannot get anything even closely related to what I want.
Another idea I have is to use the picture above as a background image and remove border and background from the qlineedit to make it seem like it's a part of the picture. The problem with this approach is that it will not be stretchable anymore.

Is it even possible to make my qlineedit look like the one in the picture or should I just abandon this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by subclassing QLineEdit and defining a custom paintEvent. QFontMetrics will get the width and height of the text to be added as a label on the QLineEdit. Then it can be used to define a desired `margin-top` and clipped border space. The border line can be drawn with a painter path in order to have a truly transparent broken region.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class NewLineEdit(QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, label, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label = label
        self.lrect = self.fontMetrics().boundingRect(label)
        self.setStyleSheet(f'''
        QLineEdit {{
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0%);
            border: none;
            padding: 9px;
            margin-top: {self.lrect.height() / 2}px;
            color: blue;
        }}''')
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, False)
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.lrect.width() + 52)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        lh = self.lrect.height() / 2
    
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(30, lh + 3)
        path.lineTo(9, lh + 3)
        path.quadTo(3, lh + 3, 3, lh + 9)
        path.lineTo(3, h - 9)
        path.quadTo(3, h - 3, 9, h - 3)
        path.lineTo(w - 9, h - 3)
        path.quadTo(w - 3, h - 3, w - 3, h - 9)
        path.lineTo(w - 3, lh + 9)
        path.quadTo(w - 3, lh + 3, w - 9, lh + 3)
        path.lineTo(42 + self.lrect.width(), lh + 3)

        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(QPen(QColor('#aaa'), 3))
        qp.drawPath(path)
        qp.setPen(Qt.black)
        qp.drawText(36, self.lrect.height(), self.label)
```

Instead of creating a QLineEdit you would create the new object such as `NewLineEdit('Input Field')`

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Quick question. When I use this class, there is a gray rectangle around text (https://imgur.com/a/VH5fMBa). Is there a way to make the background transparent? I checked the docs for drawText() but it only seems to take position and alignment tags

Comment: @afaf That's because a section of the border line has to be covered somehow, so I chose the parent's window color in order to appear transparent. Though it seems that does not work in all cases, so I've edited the answer to manually draw the line, try it now.

Comment: Edited version didn't seem to work (PySide2 5.14, python 3.6, macos catalina) the border was visible behind the text.
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        w, h = self.lrect.width(), self.lrect.height()
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(self.parent().palette().color(QPalette.Window))
        qp.drawRect(self.width() / 5 - 6, 0, w + 20, h)
        qp.setPen(Qt.black)
        qp.drawText(self.width() / 5, h, self.label)
I changed background of the parent widget and that seemed to have fixed the issue.

Comment: @afaf Copy the entire class not just the paintEvent, mine looks like this https://prnt.sc/twtpax

Comment: You are right, the edited version does work. Thank you very much for your help. Are there any resources where I learn more about styling in PyQt other than official docs?